# making a working Game Over function in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have made a platformer game and when i die i want there to be a game over scene. I have successfully been able to make a gameover scene appear on the screen saying gameover after my player sprite has showed its dead animation. However when the gameover screen takes me back to the main menu, and i click on play, it obviously takes me back to my sprite being dead. Basically after my sprite has been killed i want the animation to go back to normal(walking) rather than continue to be dead. The dead animation occurs upon collision with an enemy or trap. This seems like a very complex task and i just wanted someones opinion on it. Any help? Btw the top third of my code is the player class where the bottom two thirds are the game over screen etc...

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self,x,y,width = 65, height = 35):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.hspeed,self.vspeed = 0,0
    self.speed = 2

    self.images=[]
    r0 = pygame.image.load("Images\Player\i1.png")
    r1 = pygame.image.load("Images\Player\i2.png")
    r2 = pygame.image.load("Images\Player\i3.png")
    r3 = pygame.image.load("Images\Player\i4.png")
    self.hurt = pygame.image.load("Images\Player\Hurt.png")
    self.images.append(r0)
    self.images.append(r1)
    self.images.append(r2)
    self.images.append(r3)

    self.rotatedimages = []
    rr0 = pygame.transform.flip(r0 ,True, False)
    rr1 = pygame.transform.flip(r1 ,True, False)
    rr2 = pygame.transform.flip(r2 ,True, False)
    rr3 = pygame.transform.flip(r3 ,True, False)
    self.rotatedimages.append(rr0)
    self.rotatedimages.append(rr1)
    self.rotatedimages.append(rr2)
    self.rotatedimages.append(rr3)

    self.gravity = 0.35
    self.index = 0
    self.image = self.images[self.index]
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x,self.y,width,height)

    self.TimeNum=0
    self.TimeTarget=10
    self.Timer = 0
    self.collision = False

def update(self, event = None):
    self.calcgravity()

    self.rect.x += self.hspeed
    self.rect.y += self.vspeed

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        self.TimeNum+=1
        if self.TimeNum == self.TimeTarget:
            self.index +=1
            if self.index >= len(self.images):
                self.index = 0
            self.image = self.images[self.index]

            self.TimeNum = 0
    print(self.Timer)
    if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        self.TimeNum+=1
        if self.TimeNum == self.TimeTarget:
            self.index +=1
            if self.index >= len(self.rotatedimages):
                self.index = 0
            self.image = self.rotatedimages[self.index]
            self.TimeNum = 0

def calcgravity(self):
    if self.vspeed == 0:
        self.vspeed = 1
    else:
        self.vspeed += self.gravity

#This is what i dont understand
def dead(self):
    PlayerDead.play(loops = 0, maxtime = 100)
    self.Timer += 1
    if self.Timer >= 10:
        self.images.append(self.hurt)
        self.image = self.hurt
        self.hspeed = 0
        if self.Timer == 20:
            GameOver() 

def move(self, hspeed, vspeed):
    self.hspeed += hspeed
    self.vspeed += vspeed

def Level1PlatColl(self, BlockListGrass, TrapList, enemygroup, PowerUps):

    PlatformCollision = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, BlockListGrass, False )
    for each_object in PlatformCollision:
        if self.vspeed > 0:
            self.rect.bottom = each_object.rect.top
            self.vspeed = 0
        if self.vspeed < 0:
            self.rect.top = each_object.rect.bottom
            self.vspeed = 0

    TrapCollision = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,TrapList,False )
    for each_trap in TrapCollision:
        self.dead()
        #there might be something i could do here but i dont know what

    EnemyCollision = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,enemygroup,False )
    for each_object in EnemyCollision:
        self.dead()

    PowerUpsCollision = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,PowerUps,False )
    for speedboost in PowerUpsCollision:
        PowerUps.remove(speedboost)
def text_objects(text, font):
textSurface = font.render(text, True, (0,0,0))
return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def GameOver():
##    PlayerDead.stop()
##    SpearAttack.stop()
##    SadTrombone.play()

screen.blit(pygame.image.load("background0.jpg").convert(), (0,0))
largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("elephant",60)
TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("GameOver", largeText)
TextRect.center = ((screen_width/2),(screen_height/2))
screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

intro = True

while intro:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    Buttons("BACK TO MAIN MENU",100,500,400,50,TURQUOISE,DARK_TURQUOISE,"back")

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(15)

def Buttons(msg,x,y,w,h,inactive,active,action=None):

mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, active, (x,y,w,h))
    if click[0]==1 and action != None:
        if action == "play":
            #music.stop()
            main()
        if action == "instructions":
            Instructions()
        if action == "next_level":
            #music.stop()
            main2()
        if action == "nextlevel":
            main3()
        if action == "back":
            #music.stop()
            #this is the button where i can get back to main menu
            GameIntro()          

else:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, inactive , (x,y,w,h))

ButtonFont = pygame.font.SysFont("elephant",30)
TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(msg, ButtonFont)
TextRect.center = ((x+w/2),(y+h/2))
screen.blit(TextSurf,TextRect)
```

Comment: you have to create function which `reset` all variables before first and new game.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all the game start variables into a function so you can call it whenever you need to start the game again. Basically what you did with the game over function. Except a start game function which resets the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Define a function that initializes the game from the very beginning.
So at the first time, you start the game with calling,

```
new_game()
```

After that, when game ends you can use conditions to start a new game, or create a new **game_over()** function to handle things that can not be handled by the **new_game** function.

```
if game_ending_condition:
    new_game()
```

This way, you save yourself from the trouble of reassigning all the variables to starting values in a **game_over** function.

Comment: Ok thanks you i will try it! but is there anyway to remove of the image of my player dead when i start?

Comment: You mean removing it from the memory, or deleting it from the screen ?

Comment: i would like to delete it from screen since i would like my walking animation to run when i press my arrow keys not just a picture of my dead character.

Comment: If you use the same method to show the dead picture with the method to make the sprite run, you can easily remove the dead image by just replacing it with the running animation.