# pygame.error: display Surface quit

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, pygame, contour, pygame-surface

I am creating a python proram where we can play the classical snake xenzia game using our hand gestures and not keyboard. In this as soon as my snake gets hit on the border it the pygame window is destroyed. I then re initialize in the game function but that doesnt seem to do the trick and throws an error.I want to reinitialize the pygame window so that the user can restart the game instead of starting the game again.Any help is appreciated. Thank's in advance.This is my code:

```
import pygame, random, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *
from ctypes import windll
import time



def collide(x1, x2, y1, y2, w1, w2, h1, h2):
if x1+w1>x2 and x1<x2+w2 and y1+h1>y2 and y1<y2+h2:return True
else:return False
def die(screen, score):

    global conn,cap
    f=pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 30);t=f.render('Your score was: 
'+str(score), True, (0, 0, 0));screen.blit(t, (10, 
270));pygame.display.update();pygame.time.wait(2000)
    time.sleep(3)


    pygame.display.quit()        
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    r2 = conn.execute("select score from highscore order by score limit 10")
    sc_list = list(r2.fetchall())
    if(score <= int(max(sc_list[0])) and score >= int(min(sc_list[0]))):
            n = enter_name()
            #print(n)
            conn.execute("insert into highscore(name,score) values (?,?)",
(n,score))
    conn.commit()
    cap.release()
    #pygame.display.quit()
    #sys.exit(0)
    main_menu()

def get_name():
global e,string
string = e.get() 
return string
root1.destroy()



def enter_name():

    global root,w


    root1 = Tk()


    #global e,root1


    root1.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (700,500, 640, 100))

    b = Button(root1,text='okay',command=get_name)
    b.place(x=300,y=200)


    e = Entry(root1)
    e.place(x=250,y=150)
    e.focus_set()
    return string
    root1.mainloop()



def game():

decl()
time.sleep(2)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

global 
start,xs1,ys1,dirs1,score1,applepos1,s1,appleimage1,img1,f1,clock1,res
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake')
SetWindowPos(pygame.display.get_wm_info()['window'], -1, 0, 10, 0, 0, 
0x0001)
pygame.draw.line(s1,(255,255,255),(5,0),(5,600),3)

while (cap.isOpened()):
    #s1.fill((0,0,0))

    #SNAKE'S EXECUTION
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------
    #if(start == True):
    clock1.tick(10)
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            sys.exit(0)
        '''
        elif e.type == KEYDOWN:
            if e.key == K_UP and dirs1 != 0:dirs1 = 2
            elif e.key == K_DOWN and dirs1 != 2:dirs1 = 0
            elif e.key == K_LEFT and dirs1 != 1:dirs1 = 3
            elif e.key == K_RIGHT and dirs1 != 3:dirs1 = 1
        '''

    i = len(xs1)-1
    while i >= 2:
        if collide(xs1[0], xs1[i], ys1[0], ys1[i], 20, 20, 20, 20):die(s1, 
score1)
        i-= 1
    if collide(xs1[0], applepos1[0], ys1[0], applepos1[1], 20, 10, 20, 
   10):score1+=1;xs1.append(700);ys1.append(700);applepos1=
    (random.randint(0,590),random.randint(0,590))
    if xs1[0] < 0 or xs1[0] > 580 or ys1[0] < 0 or ys1[0] > 580:die(s1, 
   score1)
    i = len(xs1)-1
    while i >= 1:
        xs1[i] = xs1[i-1];ys1[i] = ys1[i-1];i -= 1
    if dirs1==0:
        ys1[0] += 20
    elif dirs1==1:
        xs1[0] += 20
    elif dirs1==2:
        ys1[0] -= 20
    elif dirs1==3:
        xs1[0] -= 20
    s1.fill((0,0,0))
    for i in range(0, len(xs1)):
        s1.blit(img1, (xs1[i], ys1[i]))
    s1.blit(appleimage1, applepos1);t1=f1.render(str(score1), True, 
(255,255,255));s1.blit(t1, (10, 10));pygame.display.update()

    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------

    #DETECTION'S EXECUTION
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------


    ret, img = cap.read()


    # get hand data from the rectangle sub window on the screen
    cv2.rectangle(img, (450,450), (200,200), (0,255,0),0)
    crop_img = img[200:450, 200:450]


    # convert to grayscale
    grey = cv2.cvtColor(crop_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # applying gaussian blur
    value = (35, 35)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(grey, value, 0)

    # thresholdin: Otsu's Binarization method
    _, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(blurred, 127, 255,
                           cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    # show thresholded image

    # check OpenCV version to avoid unpacking error
    (version, _, _) = cv2.__version__.split('.')

    if version == '3':
        image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh1.copy(), \
               cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    elif version == '2':
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh1.copy(),cv2.RETR_TREE, 
\
               cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    # find contour with max area
    cnt = max(contours, key = lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x))

    # create bounding rectangle around the contour (can skip below two 
lines)
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    cv2.rectangle(crop_img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 0)

    # finding convex hull
    hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)

    # drawing contours
    drawing = np.zeros(crop_img.shape,np.uint8)
    cv2.drawContours(drawing, [cnt], 0, (0, 255, 0), 0)
    cv2.drawContours(drawing, [hull], 0,(0, 0, 255), 0)

    # finding convex hull
    hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt, returnPoints=False)

    # finding convexity defects
    defects = cv2.convexityDefects(cnt, hull)
    count_defects = 0
    cv2.drawContours(thresh1, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

    # applying Cosine Rule to find angle for all defects (between fingers)
    # with angle > 90 degrees and ignore defects
    for i in range(defects.shape[0]):
        s,e,f,d = defects[i,0]

        start = tuple(cnt[s][0])
        end = tuple(cnt[e][0])
        far = tuple(cnt[f][0])

        # find length of all sides of triangle
        a = math.sqrt((end[0] - start[0])**2 + (end[1] - start[1])**2)
        b = math.sqrt((far[0] - start[0])**2 + (far[1] - start[1])**2)
        c = math.sqrt((end[0] - far[0])**2 + (end[1] - far[1])**2)

        # apply cosine rule here
        angle = math.acos((b**2 + c**2 - a**2)/(2*b*c)) * 57

        # ignore angles > 90 and highlight rest with red dots
        if angle <= 90:
            count_defects += 1
            cv2.circle(crop_img, far, 1, [0,0,255], -1)
        #dist = cv2.pointPolygonTest(cnt,far,True)

        # draw a line from start to end i.e. the convex points (finger tips)
        # (can skip this part)
        cv2.line(crop_img,start, end, [0,255,0], 2)
        #cv2.circle(crop_img,far,5,[0,0,255],-1)

    # define actions required
    if count_defects == 1 and dirs1 != 0:
        dirs1 = 2
        #print('!!!!!!!!!1')        
        start=True
    elif count_defects == 2 and dirs1 != 2:
        dirs1 = 0
    elif count_defects == 3 and dirs1 != 1:
        dirs1 = 3
    elif count_defects == 4 and dirs1 != 3:
        dirs1 = 1

    all_img = np.hstack((drawing, crop_img))
    cv2.imshow('Contours', all_img)
    cv2.imshow('Thresholded', thresh1)

    # show appropriate images in windows
    cv2.imshow('Gesture', img)
    #cv2.resizeWindow('Gesture',800,800)
    cv2.moveWindow('Gesture',700,50)
    k = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if k == 27:
        break
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------
```

Comment: Please [format your code correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). Aside from that, I gather that you would like to destroy the window and then reopen it. I can tell you that there is no need to do that just to start a new game. Also, remove uses of `time.sleep()`. Uses of this line are not meant to be used with pygame and don't work properly.

Comment: Consider the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866584/making-a-working-game-over-function-in-pygame) which answers how to start a new game in pygame.